# Prove there exist basis that contains no vector from linear span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let ($a_1,...,a_{k+1}$) - linearly independent vectors. Prove that linear span $L(a_1,...,a_{k+1})$ has basis that contains no vector from linear span $L(a_1, ..., a_k)$.

Let's just say, I do not quite understand the condition of the problem. Could you help me with it?

Comment: The problem is nonsense for me. I sure that $L(a_1,..,a_k) \subset L(a_1,...,a_{k+1})$. How I can choose basis from $L(a_1,...,a_{k+1})$. brrr

Comment: Since $L(a_1,...,a_{k+1})$ is a vector space, it certainly has a basis. Your task is to show that you can find one where no vector **of that basis** is in $L(a_1,...,a_k)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with
$$
\{a_1-a_{k+1},a_2-a_{k+1},\dots,a_k-a_{k+1},a_{k+1}\}
$$